# Replacing for loop with while loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have a dynamic range of rows in this api i am calling. I have looked at some prior use of while loops but I cant seem to figure out how to swap the for loop in this script out for a while loop.

```
header = ["fanduel", "fd_first_name", "fd_last_name", "fd_player_salary", "draftkings", "dk_first_name", "dk_last_name", "dk_player_salary"]
headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " +
                base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
    }

with open("dailydfs.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for fordate in range(20171215,20171216):  #ENTER DATE'S
        req = requests.get(url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/daily_dfs.json?fordate=" + str(fordate) , headers=headers)
        req.raise_for_status()
        data = req.json()

        daily_dfs = data['dailydfs']

        fanduel = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsType']
        draftkings = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][1]['dfsType']

        for i in range(20):

            fd_player = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsRows'][i]['player']
            salary_fd = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsRows'][i]
            fd_last_name = fd_player['LastName']
            fd_first_name = fd_player['FirstName']
            fd_player_salary = salary_fd['salary']

            dk_player = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][1]['dfsRows'][i]['player']
            salary_dk = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][1]['dfsRows'][i]
            dk_last_name = dk_player['LastName']
            dk_first_name = dk_player['FirstName']
            dk_player_salary = salary_dk['salary']

            writer.writerow([fanduel, fd_first_name, fd_last_name, fd_player_salary, draftkings, dk_first_name, dk_last_name, dk_player_salary])
            print(fanduel, fd_first_name, fd_last_name, fd_player_salary, draftkings, dk_first_name, dk_last_name, dk_player_salary)
```

OUTPUT:

```
FanDuel Jonathan Quick    8800  DraftKings Martin Jones      8400
FanDuel Henrik Lundqvist  8600  DraftKings Aaron Dell        8300
FanDuel Frederik Andersen 8500  DraftKings Frederik Andersen 8200
FanDuel Martin Jones      8500  DraftKings Curtis McElhinney 8100
FanDuel Ben Bishop        8500  DraftKings Cory Schneider    7900
FanDuel Cory Schneider    8200  DraftKings Tyler Seguin      7800
```

Comment: Which for are you talking about?

Comment: Some days there are more `players` playing than others. If I leave it in a for loop i will have to check to see how many there are and change the `range()` daily. Point of the script is to automate a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that both `daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsRows']` and `daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][1]['dfsRows']` have the same number of elements, you can enumerate the first one and use the index when obtaining the second, i.e.

```
for i, fd_info in enumerate(daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsRows']):
    fd_player = fd_info['player']
    fd_last_name = fd_player['LastName']
    fd_first_name = fd_player['FirstName']
    fd_player_salary = fd_info['salary']

    dk_info = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][1]['dfsRows'][i]
    dk_player = dk_info['player']
    dk_last_name = dk_player['LastName']
    dk_first_name = dk_player['FirstName']
    dk_player_salary = dk_info['salary']

    # etc.
```

Comment: Sorry I did not specify that. They will not have the same number of elements. Typically the second or `dk_` will have more.

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson - how do you plan to join them in the same table row?

Comment: Edit: See Output above.         Since dk usally has more players available i just switch your `fd_info` to `dk_info` but i still run into `fd_info = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsRows'][i]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Your saying I should write a separate script for both right? Might make it easier for storage. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson - the above example doesn't do anything to show how would you deal with uneven number of entries. You'll of course be getting an `IndexError` if you're trying to access an out-of-bounds index in the shorter of the two. The question is - what do you do with the data when the lengths are uneven? You can either throw away the excess data, add empty entries, add default entries or cycle the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
    fd_player = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsRows'][i]['player']
    salary_fd = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][0]['dfsRows'][i]
    fd_last_name = fd_player['LastName']
    fd_first_name = fd_player['FirstName']
    fd_player_salary = salary_fd['salary']

    dk_player = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][1]['dfsRows'][i]['player']
    salary_dk = daily_dfs['dfsEntries'][1]['dfsRows'][i]
    dk_last_name = dk_player['LastName']
    dk_first_name = dk_player['FirstName']
    dk_player_salary = salary_dk['salary']

    writer.writerow([fanduel, fd_first_name, fd_last_name, fd_player_salary, draftkings, dk_first_name, dk_last_name,
                     dk_player_salary])
    print(
    fanduel, fd_first_name, fd_last_name, fd_player_salary, draftkings, dk_first_name, dk_last_name, dk_player_salary)
    i+=1
```

Comment: thank you, but this will only pull the first element not run through all of them.